# Issue Kafka Mirror Maker updated from 1.0.2 to 2.2.0 - Failed to construct consumer - No resolvable bootstrap urls

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Recently I updated kafka mirror and now it can't connect to source zk servers - consumer fails.
Previous version was based on java:openjdk-8-jre, kafka_2.11-1.0.2.tgz and zookeeper:3.4.10. 
I updated kafka to kafka_2.12-2.2.0.tgz, staying on same 3.4.10 zk version and java:openjdk-8-jre. 
Problem is that when I start kafka mirror, now on 2.2.0, I get a very weird error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:49)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:721)
        ... 13 more
```

If I switch kafka mirror back to old docker image 1.0.2 - it works. 
I tried with IP address of source zoo servers, same error. 
Can someone please help me with the error and is there something specifically for 2.2.0 mirror maker? Only difference is kafka i upgraded from 1.0.0 to 2.2.0 - everything else remains the same.

Comment: In the consumer.properties, are you setting `bootstrap.servers` the same? The error is not about Zookeepers

Comment: well, it's embarrassing, but there was no `bootstrap.servers` variable in consumer.properties, only `zookeeper-connect`, which seems to be deprecated.
Now problem is resolved as I have updated consumer.properties to latest ConsumerConfig class.
Thank you @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comment to answer...

The error seems to be indicating that you have misconigured the `bootstrap.servers` property in the `consumer.properties` file.

Using Zookeeper as solely the connection string shouldn't be used on any of the Kafka versions you mentioned.